# Test Driven Development with React Context API and RestFul API

Tags: rest, tdd

I want to refactor complex filtering I created a while ago and now I would like to use TDD.
Questions about best practice:

1. I'm refactoring data coming from a Restful API. Is it better to use the API directly (I can create a mock DB for my testing needs) or is it better to use the mock data, i.e. JSON file?
2. is it ok to simply import functions and states from the Context API into the testing file?

Answer (score 0):

Test-driven development (TDD) is the process of writing a test and using the test as a critique of the System Under Test (SUT). Write a test, and then implement the SUT in the simplest possible way.

With the Red Green Refactor process, after each red-green phase, you're supposed to consider the SUT and think about possible improvements.

For example, if the test itself becomes too complicated, it's feedback that the SUT ought to be simplified.

Data filtering is typically [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which means that they're [trivial to unit test](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/05/07/functional-design-is-intrinsically-testable): Pass appropriate input to the function and verify that the output is equal to the expected output.

You don't need to involve a real service, a Test Double, or even a data file to do this.

Comment: Thanks. By that, you mean that I don't need to have a test file with the DB?

Comment: @MarcoDisco I don't know your specific scenario, so I can't answer with certainty, but [a filter function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)) is a pure function, so the only thing you need in order to test it is input and its corresponding expected output. These values can come from anywhere, code, files, databases, etc. but why make it more complicated than it has to be? Is there a reason you can't define data in code?

Comment: Sorry, my fault then. I meant a Filtering system for the database. So it's not just a function but a bunch of functions returning the desired values.

Comment: @MarcoDisco What's _'a Filtering system for the database?'_ Which database? Written in which language? How does it differ from a function composed from other functions?

Comment: The language is Javascript, the framework is React.